# Key Codes for QWERTY phones j2me

Tags: java-me

I'm currently doing a j2me project, and I am wondering what key code I will use for the keylistener when I press letters like A, B, C, etc?

I'm deploying the j2me in a QWERTY phone - SAMSUNG CH@T 223.

Comment: So make a midlet which prints key codes to screen and see what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [`Canvas.keyPressed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#keyPressed%28int%29) the `keyCode` parameter will hold the Unicode value of the corresponding character of the pressed key.
Depending on the keyboard mode the value might vary. For example, the same key might generate 'd', 'D' or '4'.
The modes are: normal (lower case letters), shift/caps (high case letters) and alt (numbers and symbols).

Comment: is it the same when dealing with QWERTY Phones?

Comment: I can say yes for sure for Samsung and Motorola phones.